# What is the difference between CMake variables and properties?

Tags: cmake

CMake variables and properties seem to accomplish very similar things, and I have been unable to understand the difference between them.

They each have their own sections of documentation, but both can affect the build system, both "pre-exist", and both can be dynamically generated based on other CMake commands. It seems like they should have separate purposes. What are they?

Comment: In a property you can construct the name from a composite token, like `<name>:<os_name>:<config_name>:<arch_name>` and so on, and parse it as a standalone variable using regexp or whatever you want. In a variable name you can not use this technique because a variable name must not contain invalid characters like `:`. So properties together with each other can be used to some kind structure variable values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I felt not entirely satisfied by the other answers, so I had to go and find my own. After some reading and consulting, I believe the roles CMake intends for variables and properties are indeed different, and in fact more or less straightforward.

**Variables** are arbitrarily named memory cells you use *during calculations and to pass values around*. They can also be assigned in the command line and exposed as GUI options, *to accept inputs from outside* of the script.

**Properties** are predefined slots that together describe all aspects of the environment, the state and the project being configured. Remember that the point of running CMake is to have the selected generator output a set of makefiles (or IDE project files). In turn, the point of the configuration stage is to evaluate and note down all **the facts** that the generator might want to know when it is making its decisions.

So in general, values would flow throug cmake like this:

> command line/option > variable > some processing > property >
> generator > makefile

For example, **CXX_STANDARD prop** can be set via set_property(), but will also initialize from the **CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD var** if it was given a value.

In "modern" CMake we are encouraged to think in terms of targets and the properties they have, instead of setting values to a disorganized bunch of variables, but properties weren't there initially it seems so some aspects can still be configured using variables.
For example, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS var can be set to "-std=c++11" and will then affect the generation directly. **The modern way is to set CXX_STANDARD prop instead.**

Comment: So in other words, properties are intended to affect the build system and any variables there are that do that are legacy and presumably remain for backwards compatibility. I can accept that. Accepting this as the answer for now as it’s the first answer that truly answered the intent of my question in the fullest sense.

Answer (score 14):

A very short and simple way to think about it is that properties are variables scoped to a target.  For example:

```
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 14
    CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
)
# Build foo with c++11 for some reason
add_executable(foo11 foo.cpp)
set_target_properties(foo11 PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
)
```

If CMakeLists.txt was written in C++, that might look something like this:

```
const char * src_files[] = { "foo.cpp" };
executable foo{src_files};
foo.setCxxStandard(14);
foo.setCxxExtensions(false);

executable foo11{src_files};
foo.setCxxStandard(11);
foo.setCxxExtensions(false);
```

If we used variables for these things, it'd look more like this:

```
// globals
int CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD = 14;
bool CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS = false;

// later, in a function
const char * src_files[] = { "foo.cpp" };
executable foo{src_files}; // foo copies global settings

CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD = 11;
executable foo11{src_files};
```

Because properties are part of a target instead of globals, this also means they can be exported.  Sanitized rom one of my projects:

```
set_target_properties(Foo::bar PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES "cxx_std_14"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/"
    INTERFACE_SOURCES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include/foo/bar.hpp"
)
```

This means if you import `Foo::bar` (probably through something like `find_package(Foo)`), your project already knows that things linking against `Foo::bar` need to use C++14 (`INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES`), it needs to add something to the include path (`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`), and there are some source files it cares about (my headers, `INTERFACE_SOURCES`).

Comment: Ah, I think i may understand the difference as properties may be scoped whereas variables are always global. Except according to the properties documentation here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-properties.7.html properties may also be global, so in that case it is still confusing to me and the distinction seems arbitrary.

Comment: @user1489829 - I'll admit I wasn't aware of the global properties, so I'd have to figure that one out.  My answer is specifically for properties on targets, but the comparison could be expanded for any non-global property.

Comment: As denoted by user1489829, there are also properties of Global Scope, which makes this answer incorrect. So, I'd still like to get a correct and more comprehensive answer. As of May 2018, googling this question gives nothing useful.

Comment: CMake is not very coherent IMHO...deal with it.

Answer (score 6):

I think Stephen Newell's answer captures the main motivation for properties (and the c++ analogy of member variables vs non-member variables is very helpful).

However, in addition to *target properties*, which are scoped to targets there are various other kinds which can instead be scoped to eg *source, install, directory, global* etc.

Its possible to have a (*'global'*) variable and (global) property with the same name exist simultaneously (but the usefulness of such is not obvious).

In summary, properties are primarily useful for their being "scoped" to something like a target. Global properties are also scoped to a single "global object". (In Stephen's analogy they might be member variables of a singleton). Properties are set/get with a different syntax to variables. And a property with a given scope can simultaneously exist with others of the same name in any other scope (including global) as well as a regular variable of the same name.

One possible usefulness of combining global properties and variables is given  [here](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/basics/variables.html):

> A global property can be a useful uncached global variable. Many
> target properties are initialised from a matching variable with CMAKE_
> at the front. So setting CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD, for example, will mean
> that all new targets created will have CXX_STANDARD set to that when
> they are created

Comment: For me, this is a more complete explanation as it describes all the property types, then goes on to generalise the concept

Answer (score -1):

First, how do programming languages handle variables? Variables in programming languages can be divided into two groups.
Stack based or object based.

- Stack based variables are variables that is stored in memory that each function reserves, memory found on stack. The reserved area on the stack grows and shrinks all the time when functions are called. When a new function is entered that function reserves memory for variables on top of the stack. Leaving function will destroy the area and variables are wiped.
- Object based variables is stored in the memory area that is reserved for the object. Object based variables are destroyed when the object is destroyed. They are usually destroyed by some type of operation / command. These type of object variables are sometimes called member variables.

Script languages works like this too, but they have tricks to simulate the stack. When a function is entered in a script language the stack is usually also one object. That object knows about it's caller stack.
It works like a tree where variable branches grow and shrink, each branch knows about its parent and has leaves that are variables here.
The start-up time for running script programs can't be too long, so there is a limited amount of time when it comes to analyzing the code to optimize it. This stack tree that exists in script languages is a trade-off and makes them much simpler to parse and analyze compared to a language that stores variables on the stack as the computer processor can handle it.

So how do variables and properties work in CMake. I haven't checked the code but I can guess. Variables is stack based, properties are object based. Printing variable value with message need a stack based variable, the message command can find variables stored on stack. It can't find properties because they are members to one objects in CMake. To get a value from a property you also need the object and that is why you need another command to get it like get_property .

[Here is a  CMake tutorial](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=api&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7107&link=%5B%5B%229F1E006D78894848838A0970E2FF0BE9zoom%22,%22Object1%22,7107%5D%5D&rows=25)

Comment: "I haven't checked the code but I can guess."